# Check if string has a format: str-str-str. Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check if string has the aforementioned format when user input string.

Examples of **acceptable** strings:

1. string
2. home-appliances
3. such-a-long-word-but-still-valid

Examples of **disallowed** strings:

1. home-appliances**-**
2. home-appliances- smth-else
3. -home-appliances
4. -home-appliances-
5. string-with-digits**23132**-fails
6. string-with-a-lot---------of-dashes
7. string.with-some-other-symbols-except-dashes

Every regex that I tried - not successfully validate strings.
For example, the following regex expression

```js
/^[a-z][a-z-]+[a-z]$/
```

does not meet many conditions.

I will be glad to your help, thanks a lot

Comment: I'm guessing [`^[^-]\S*[^-]$`](https://regex101.com/r/wA1x9n/1) won't be enough? Can you add some strings which that should fail matching?

Comment: add more fail strings

Comment: and also 1 allowed string(just 1 word)

Comment: Would you consider a non-regex solution? You might want to do `str.split('-')` and make sure all elements are non-empty.

Comment: As for the project - perhaps this is a suitable option. But it is important to find out if it is possible to implement such behavior by using regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a group matching `(-[a-z]+)` and match that repeating zero or more times after your initial alpha-characters

```js
const good = [
  "string",
  "home-appliances",
  "such-a-long-word-but-still-valid",
];

const bad = [
  "home-appliances-",
  "home-appliances- smth-else",
  "-home-appliances",
  "-home-appliances-",
  "string-with-digits23132-fails",
  "string-with-a-lot---------of-dashes",
  "string.with-some-other-symbols-except-dashes",
];

const rx = /^[a-z]+(-[a-z]+)*$/;

const check = (str) => console.log(str, rx.test(str) ? "✅" : "❌");
good.forEach(check);
bad.forEach(check);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```